# Multiply all values in a %hash and return a %hash with the same structure

Tags: raku, rakudo

I have some JSON stored in a database column that looks like this:

```
pokeapi=# SELECT height FROM pokeapi_pokedex WHERE species = 'Ninetales';
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------------
height | {"default": {"feet": "6'07\"", "meters": 2.0}}
```

As part of a 'generation' algorithm I'm working on I'd like to take this value into a %hash, multiply it by `(0.9..1.1).rand` (to allow for a 'natural 10% variance in the height), and then create a new %hash in the same structure. My `select-height` method looks like this:

```
method select-height(:$species, :$form = 'default') {
    my %heights = $.data-source.get-height(:$species, :$form);

    my %height = %heights * (0.9..1.1).rand;

    say %height;
}
```

Which actually calls my `get-height` routine to get the 'average' heights (in both metric and imperial) for that species.

```
method get-height (:$species, :$form) {
    my $query = dbh.prepare(qq:to/STATEMENT/);
           SELECT height FROM pokeapi_pokedex WHERE species = ?;
        STATEMENT

    $query.execute($species);

    my %height = from-json($query.row);
    my %heights = self.values-or-defaults(%height, $form);

    return %heights;
}
```

However I'm given the following error on execution (I assume because I'm trying to multiple the hash as a whole rather than the individual elements of the hash):

```
$ perl6 -I lib/ examples/height-weight.p6
{feet => 6'07", meters => 2}
Odd number of elements found where hash initializer expected:
Only saw: 1.8693857987465123e0
  in method select-height at /home/kane/Projects/kawaii/p6-pokeapi/lib/Pokeapi/Pokemon/Generator.pm6 (Pokeapi::Pokemon::Generator) line 22
  in block <unit> at examples/height-weight.p6 line 7
```

Is there an easier (and working) way of doing this without duplicating my code for each element? :)

Comment: Use hyperops, eg. `my %hash = :a, :b; say %hash».rand # {a => 0.12201023810083333, b => 0.3360358162308337}`

Comment: Also, if you don't process `%heights` in the `get-height` method, you can just remote it along with `return` statement, leaving only a method call to `values-or-defaults`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, there is an issue with logic of your code. Initially, you are getting a hash of values, `"feet": "6'07\"", "meters": 2.0` parsed out of json, with `meters` being a number and `feet` being a string. Next, you are trying to multiply it on a random value... And while it will work for a number, it won't for a string. Perl 6 allomorphs allow you to do that, actually: `say "5" * 3` will return `15`, but `X"Y'` pattern is complex enough for Perl 6 to not naturally understand it.

So you likely need to convert it before processing, and to convert it back afterwards.

The second thing is exact line that leads to the error you are observing.

Consider this:

```
my %a = a => 5;
%a = %a * 10 => 5; # %a becomes a hash with a single value of 10 => 5
# It happens because when a Hash is used in math ops, its size is used as a value
# Thus, if you have a single value, it'll become 1 * 10, thus 10
# And for %a = a => 1, b => 2; %a * 5 will be evaluated to 10
%a = %a * 10; # error, the key is passed, but not a value
```

To work directly on hash values, you want to use `map` method and process every pair, for example: `%a .= map({ .key => .value * (0.9..1.1).rand })`.

Of course, it can be golfed or written in another manner, but the main issue is resolved this way.

Comment: Or change the values in place using metaoperator: `%a >>*=>> (0.9 .. 1.1).rand`

Answer (score 5):

You've accepted @Takao's answer. That solution requires manually digging into `%hash` to get to leaf hashes/lists and then applying `map`.

Given that your question's title mentions "return ... *same* ***structure***" and the body includes what looks like a *nested* structure, I think it's important there's an answer providing some idiomatic solutions for automatically descending into and duplicating a nested structure:

```
my %hash = :a{:b{:c,:d}}

say my %new-hash = %hash».&{ (0.9 .. 1.1) .rand }
# {a => {b => {c => 1.0476391741359872, d => 0.963626602773474}}}

# Update leaf values of original `%hash` in-place:
%hash».&{ $_ = (0.9 .. 1.1) .rand }

# Same effect:
%hash »*=» (0.9..1.1).rand;

# Same effect:
%hash.deepmap: { $_ = (0.9..1.1).rand }
```

[Hyperops](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#index-entry-hyper_%3C%3C-hyper_%3E%3E-hyper_%C2%AB-hyper_%C2%BB-Hyper_operators) (eg `»`) iterate one or two data structures to get to their leaves and then apply the op being hypered:

```
say %hash».++ # in-place increment leaf values of `%hash` even if nested
```

`.&{ ... }` calls the closure in braces using method call syntax. Combining this with a hyperop one can write:

```
%hash».&{ $_ = (0.9 .. 1.1) .rand }
```

Another option is [`.deepmap`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/deepmap):

```
%hash.deepmap: { $_ = (0.9..1.1).rand }
```

A key difference between hyperops and deepmap is that the compiler is allowed to iterate data structures and run hyperoperations in parallel in any order whereas `deepmap` iteration always occurs sequentially.